# JavaScript Object is not recognized after defined using WebPack Encore in Symfony 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, symfony4, webpack-encore

I am trying to include BootstrapDialog in a Symfony 4 project using WebPack Encore.

First, I copied the Bootstrap Dialog JS file to the JS folder where all other JS files reside.

Second, I have done this in app.js file:

```
require('./bootstrap-dialog');

global.$ = global.jQuery = $;

alert(BootstrapDialog);
```

Third I have added this inside bootstrap dialog JS file.

```
alert(BootstrapDialog);
```

Notice the alert in app.js and the alert in the bootstrap dialog js file.

The alert in the bootstrap dialog js file shows the BootstrapDialog function body, however, the alert in app.js caused this to be displayed in browser console window:

```
 ReferenceError: BootstrapDialog is not defined
```

How can I make BootstrapDialog function to be accesible from outside its own JS file?

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootbox (http://bootboxjs.com/)

In app.js or other, you write 
**bootbox = require('bootbox');**

That's all

You can use it :

- bootbox.alert("Your message here…")
- bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result){
  /* your callback code */ 
  })

...